# Repository Dropdown disappears in Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) Version 7.1

Tags: repository

After switching to PDI v7.1 two weeks ago I could connect to my repositories without a problem. Today I picked one repository as the default to connect to on startup and the Dropdown for selecting the repository disappeared. 
When starting I'm also not connected to the Repo I picked.

[image]

I found [this forum thread](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?214864-PDI-7-and-file-repository), but it didn't resolve my Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was fairly simple but totally non-intuitive.

Opening the Repository Manger in v6.1 gave me an error message, that my repositories.xml file is corrupted.

Opening it up in a decent editor (Sublime Text) and saving it with utf-8 encoding helped. After that, when starting Spoon again the Repository Dropdown is back in place and I can connect to my repos.

It's still a bug, since as soon as the Repository Manager writes to repositories.xml  the file get's corrupted.